# Can we exclude jquery-1.8.3.min.js from openapi-generator-maven-plugin-6.5.0 in maven

Tags: openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have added openapi-generator-maven-plugin-6.5.0 dependency in my project and want to exclude jquery-1.8.3.min.js due to security issues. Is there any way i can do that? just like we exclude transitive dependencies?